# Printing a base R plot in Rstudio to a png independent of the plotting region size with in my rstudio browser

Tags: plot, size, rstudio

I would like to print a png image of a **base** R plot within Rstudio with dimensions of a different size than in my current **Rstudio** browser.

Sometimes when I create figures, they are dependent on the current size of my plotting region within **Rstudio** and this causes distorted images that come out looking squished or not the way I intended.

Is there a way to create a png image of a standard size every time, say 8 x 10 inches.

I know this can be accomplished using the base R GUI or by using another type of plotting function such as ggplot2. However, I want to accomplish this with the base plot function and **Rstudio**.

I am also aware that I can choose a custom size manually within the plotting window, but this becomes hard to do if I am producing hundreds of plots automatically.

Comment: do you want to save the plotted image into your file system ?
Does base R plot mean plot() ??

Comment: Yes into my file system. And yes using the plot() function

Answer (score 2):

The png graphic device can be used to set the dimensions and other properties of subsequent plot. Note the parameters units and res.

```
png(filename="myimereg",width=10,height = 8, units = "in", res = 120)

plot(c(1:10),c(1:10))

dev.off()
```